# Help analyzing data ranked on a scale

Tags: mathematical-statistics, ranking, agreement-statistics

So, I thought it would be interesting to try an experiment with my family. I baked 13 different kinds cookies this year, and then told my 8 family members to rank from each cookie from 1-13. Is there any statistical analysis I can do? Obviously I added up for each cookie the ranks and got a number. 3 of the cookies came out to be 66 which would indicate they have the highest sum of rankings. What statistics can I do on this data?

Comment: What's the goal of your analysis?  To see how the cookies might perform with a larger audience?  If you are only concerned with how the cookies perform at home among your 8 family members, I don't think you'd need to perform any statistical testing as your analysis is already of the population data (and not a sample), unless you are considering your single baking a sample of an infinite number of baking "experiments" in which each baking could result in different ratings, even if the recipe remains unchanged.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that makes sense what you are saying. It is the population. In that case, I guess the way to tell the true winner for best cookie is by tallying up the rankings!

Comment: What question do you want answered from the data? Some kind of *average ranking*? Or to see if the family members more or less agree? Or, maybe interesting, find which fam members disagree with the rest, and how? Or describe which recipies cause much agreement? If you could post your data we coukd have a look ...